# Java Animation Method

Tags: java, swing, animation

Comparing `javax.swing.Timer`, `java.util.Timer` and `Thread`, which method is the best CPU utilization for animation in Java and why ? The other method that not mentioned is also accepted.

Comment: None of these have much to do with animation.  What they have in common is that they are non-input things that can put events on the UI thread.  The differences among them have little to do with CPU utilization.

Comment: So EDT will make thread safe operation for GUI right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When working with GUI components you should **always** use `javax.swing.Timer` for animations.

The swing timer will help you execute your animation tasks on the correct thread. (The Event Dispatch Thread, or EDT)

To answer your specific question:

> which method is the best CPU utilization for animation in Java and why ?

If used correctly, neither will affect CPU performance in a positive or negative way.  They will essentially provide the exact same functionality.